# slideToggle slides up then down when called from a function

Tags: jquery

I have a button to toggle a div. The function is:

```
function toggleMiniCart() {
 $('#mini_cart_more').click( function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    e.stopPropagation();
        $('#mini_cart_dropdown').slideToggle('fast');
        if($('#mini_cart_dropdown').css('display') == 'none') {
    $(this).addClass('mini_cart_less');
    $(this).removeClass('mini_cart_more');  
        }  
        else {
     $(this).removeClass('mini_cart_less');
     $(this).addClass('mini_cart_more');
    }                   
  })
}
```

I have called the function in the document load like:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
   toggleMiniCart();
});
```

This works fine. However, when I call it from another function and the #mini_cart_more is clicked the div slides down, then back up.

```
function add_to_cart() {
   $('.add_to_cart').click(function() {
       //do some ajax
       toggleMiniCart();
   });
}
```

Comment: I am using that. I think the issue is how/where I am calling

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is that it's trying to add a click function each time that `toggleMiniCart` is ran. Place the click listener outside of the function and reference it in the click listener instead like so:

```
function toggleMiniCart() {
    $elem = $("#mini_cart_dropdown");
    $elem.slideToggle('fast');
    if($elem.css('display') == 'none') {
        $elem.addClass('mini_cart_less');
        $elem.removeClass('mini_cart_more');  
    } else {
        $elem.removeClass('mini_cart_less');
        $elem.addClass('mini_cart_more');
    }                   
}
function add_to_cart() {
   $('.add_to_cart').click(function() {
       //do some ajax
       toggleMiniCart();
   });
}

$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#mini_cart_more').click( function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        e.stopPropagation();
        toggleMiniCart();
    });
});
```

Comment: This appears to be working, except I had to remove the toggleMiniCart(); that is outside the click event in the document.ready. Having it there caused the mini cart to open on page load. Other than that the icon for the dropdown is not changing $elem.addClass('mini_cart_less');, but I am looking at that.

Comment: If you remove the call to toggleMiniCart() in the $(document).ready I can accept this. This causes it to toggle on page load. Thanks.

Comment: @Judson Removed as per request